# Множественный звук при зажатии кнопки java android

Tags: java

Как сделать так ,чтобы при зажатии кнопки воспроизводился звук, а при отжатии он прекращался?

Comment: Такое часто используется в приложениях, типо звуки оружия.При зажатии там кнопки звук идет пока ее не отпустишь

Answer (score 1):

Вам сюда http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html
У View элементов есть события на все случаи жизни и на них можно вешать слушателей.

Comment: Ответы-ссылки не приветствуются сообществом, так как информация по ссылке может измениться и ваш ответ станет бесполезным. Постарайтесь указать информацию, требующуюся для ответа на вопрос в своём сообщении, а статью можно привести в качестве источника информации.