# При ЗАЖАТИИ кнопки воспроизводится звук, а при отжатии он пропадает .Как это реализовать?

Tags: java

ТАкое часто используется в приложениях оружие звук. Когда ты нажимаешь на оружие оно стреляет, а когда отжимаешь звук пропадает

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Множественный звук при зажатии кнопки java android](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442808/%d0%9c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-java-android)

Comment: У меня плохо с английским . Я там ничего не пойму

Comment: воспользуйтесь, пожалуйста, [любым онлайн-переводчиком](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%9E%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8)